# Shared provisioning in CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

We have our MongoDB database which data we want to restore to **Azure's CosmosDB**. First, we did that with mongorestore and the result is that for each collection Cosmos configures 1000 RU/s throughput.

The thing is that we have 41 collections and the overall price does not fit to the current budget, so we use so-called **shared throughput** which is set on database level. But the thing is that when we execute mongorestore again, Cosmos expects to have shard keys for each collection.

Is there any way to overcome this issue using mongorestore with shared throughput on database level?

Answer (score 0):

@Nikola Thanks for your feedback.

Partition Key is used for sharding, it acts as a logical partition for your data, and provides Cosmos DB with a natural boundary for distributing data across partitions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data

While for migration from Mongo DB to Cosmos DB you can use Azure Data Migration Service.
Tutorial for same : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-mongodb-cosmos-db?toc=/azure/cosmos-db/toc.json

Hope this helps.